# Click & Double Click Events on Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm trying to get tap / doubletap things to work on mobile browsers.  I have the following code:

```
$(function() {
  $(".vppop").mouseenter(function() { // Desktop browsers only
      $(".vppop").addClass("vppopscale");
  });
  $(".vppop").mouseleave(function() { // Desktop browsers only
      $(".vppop").removeClass("vppopscale");
  });
  $(".vppop").on('tap', function(e) { // Mobile browsers only
      e.preventDefault(); // Stop from following link
      $(".vppop").addClass("vppopscale").delay(300).removeClass("vppopscale");
  });
  $(".vppop").on('doubletap', function() { // Mobile browsers only
      // Go to Link
  });
});
```

Using finger plugin for mobile events:  https://github.com/ngryman/jquery.finger

Can't get tap event to prevent link following & not sure what I need for doubletap event to get it to follow link.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

I've just seen this question. This is perhaps too late, but if you update *Finger* to the latest version you will be able to prevent default behavior this way. This was not supported in older versions.

However, if you attach both `tap` and `doubletap` event listeners to the same element, and that `tap` prevents default behavior, then it will also apply for the `doubletap`.

So you might want to open the link manually in your `doubletap` listener:

```
$(".vppop").on('doubletap', function() { // Mobile browsers only
    window.location = this.href;
});
```

Hope this helps, even if it's a little late :)